# convert string to php array, jquery serialize on form

Tags: php, jquery

I have a form and am sending the data to a backend php script using:

```
var fields = $('#myform').serializeArray();
```

And then doing a post.  Some of my inputs are named as arrays so when the data gets posted, I have an array like below.  How do I convert the attribute pieces back into one attribute array with sub arrays?

```
[1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(20) "attribute[26][higher]"
    ["value"]=>
    string(2) "21"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(20) "attribute[27][higher]"
    ["value"]=>
    string(2) "20"
  }
```

Comment: Could you send the data as JSON instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eval`

FORM PHP DOC

> The eval() language construct is very dangerous because it allows execution of arbitrary PHP code. Its use thus is discouraged. If you have carefully verified that there is no other option than to use this construct, pay special attention not to pass any user provided data into it without properly validating it beforehand.

```
$array = array(array("name" => "attribute[26][higher]","value" => "21"),array("name" => "attribute[27][higher]","value" => "20"));
foreach ( $array as $value ) {
    $value["name"]  = str_replace(array("[","]") ,  array("['","']"),  $value["name"]);
    eval("\$" . $value["name"] . " =  array() ;" );
    eval("\$" . $value["name"] . " = " . $value["value" ] . ";" );
}

var_dump($attribute[26]['higher'] , $attribute[27]['higher']);
```

Output

```
int 21
int 20
```